# C# Json one key have two type of value

Tags: c#, json, json.net

```
   {
      "data": {
             "cover":{"feed":"xxxxxxxx.jpg","detail":"xxxxx.jpg"}
              },
       "data":{
             "cover":"xxxxx.jpg"
             }
    }
```

The json obtained by an API is similar to the above.
"cover"may be a string or class.
How should I handle it use Newtonsoft.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Are you saying you get a response from the API with duplicate `"data"` keys? Or that the `"data"` key can have one of two structures?

Comment: `Json.Linq` allows to do it pretty easily

Comment: [Deserialize JSON-File with multiple datatypes for a key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56206243/deserialize-json-file-with-multiple-datatypes-for-a-key),Use this way.